# Doubled escape character

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, escaping

I am currently trying to do the following:

```
cmd = r'sudo sed -irn "1!N; s/<ip>127.0.0.1<\/ip>(\n.*4000.*)/<ip>0.0.0.0<\/ip>\1/" /usr/something.conf'
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

However Popen is complaining that \\1 is an invalid reference.  Upon inspecting it in pdb I see this,

```
'sudo sed -irn "1!N; s/<ip>127.0.0.1<\\/ip>(\\n.*4000.*)/<ip>0.0.0.0<\\/ip>\\1/" /usr/something.conf'
```

It appears as though python is adding an extra `\`. Is there any way to prevent that so that I can run the command as is using Popen?

Also, for simplification I left it out of the example but this is actually being wrapped in an SSH call before being passed to Popen, so yes... it does need to be done with `Popen` and `sed`.

For reference here is the full chain of steps the string goes through to be run...

```
def _formatCmd(cmdString, host=None, user=None, keyfile=None):
    cmd = []
    if host:
        cmd.append('ssh')
        keyfile = keyfile or getKeyFile()
        if keyfile:
            cmd.append('-i')
            cmd.append(keyfile)
        cmd.append("%s@%s" % (user, host))
        cmd.append(cmdString)
    else:
        cmd += cmdString.split()

    return cmd


def runCmd(host, user, cmd, timeout=None, cleanup=False):
    try:
        cmd = _formatCmd(cmd, host=host, user=user)
    except:
        pass

    #create cmd and add it to list of running cmds
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    runningCmds[proc.pid] = proc

    t = threading.Timer(timeout, proc.kill)
    t.start()
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    t.cancel()

    del runningCmds[proc.pid]
    return (proc.returncode, stdout, stderr)

cmd = r'sudo sed -irn "1!N; s/<ip>127.0.0.1<\/ip>(\n.*4000.*)/<ip>0.0.0.0<\/ip>\1/" /usr/something.conf'
runCmd('1.1.1.1', 'username', cmd)
```

The exact error message returned is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 59: invalid reference \\1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: Note that `r'\1'` is the same as `'\\1'` without the `r`. They're two ways of writing the same string. Python's not adding extra backslashes. What you're seeing is pdb printing the string in non-raw mode.

Comment: Can you post the full code without simplification, as well as the *exact* error message you're seeing? When you have escaping problems, all the layers matter.

Comment: You're escaping a string that doesn't need to be escaped by virtue of using raw notation (`cmd = r'string'`)

Comment: From what I understand is that you are executing this command with `sed` using SSH on remote machine. Since you are editing or writing to a file on remote, you can easily use `paramiko.SFTPClient` for this.

Comment: why are you usign `r''` ?

Comment: you'll have to remove the r and make it a non-raw string, and then escape what you need to.

Comment: I am using a `r''` because I want to send along the raw string without having to worry about python replacing escaped characters.  i.e. I it cant be replacing '\n' with the newline character, I need the two characters '\' and 'n'.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I've updated the question with a bit more detail.  I did notice if I used `print cmd` rather than `p cmd` I didn't get the doubled `\\ ` however this still doesn't explain the fact that sed is complaining about the `\\ ` after the command is sent over ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shell is doing its own interpreting/escaping. I found something similar when using cygwin (in the cygwin case the shell was bash).

The fact that you get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 59: invalid reference \\1 on `s' command's RHS
```

implies that it is the brackets `()` that are the problem rather than the escaping of the `\1`. Essentially, it is not able to find the group, so you need to escape the brackets `\(...\)`.

To find the cause, the trick is to use `echo` to debug what is being sent:

1. Simplify the regex to just a group and the match. Something like:

   ```
   s/(one)/\1\1/
   ```

   where the input string is 'one' and the expected output is `oneone`
2. Change your `cmd` to `echo` so that what you pass to the shell is `echo s/(one)/\1\1/`
3. I am guessing you will see something like `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`. This gives us our clue. Basically, we need to escape the brackets.
4. So now try `echo s/\(one\)/\1\1`. In my case I see something like

   ```
   s/(one)/\1\1
   ```
5. With any luck that should do it and you should be able to apply it to your problematic expression.

It may be simplest to use [strong quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) (surrounding command in single quotes) which tells bash not to interpret the string, though you will probably still have to escape the brackets `()`.

As an aside, for cygwin things need to be twice escaped, so the actual correct expression is:

```
sed s/\\\(one\\\)/\\1\\1/
```

so

```
echo one | sed s/\\\(one\\\)/\\1\\1/
```

gives

```
oneone
```

The equivalent using strong quoting is:

```
 echo one | sed 's/\(one\)/\1\1/'
```

Comment: Escaping the () was all that was missing! Thank you!